# Allowing the user to select the excel file from which to copy a worksheet into the already open worksheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have an invoicing workbook where I want to have a macro that prompts the user to select a transaction workbook. I want to then copy the selected file's single worksheet into the invoicing workbook. The following throws a runtime error 9 subscript out of range at the following line.

`transactionWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet").Copy After:=Worksheets("Export")`

Heres the code I'm working with

```
' Get transaction workbook...
Dim filter As String
Dim caption As String
Dim transactionFilename As String
Dim transactionWorkbook As Workbook
Dim invoiceWorkbook As Workbook

' make weak assumption that active workbook is the target
Set invoiceWorkbook = Application.ActiveWorkbook

' get the transaction workbook
filter = "Text files (*.xlsx),*.xlsx"
caption = "Please Select an input file "
transactionFilename = Application.GetOpenFilename(filter, , caption)

Set transactionWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(transactionFilename)

transactionWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet").Copy After:=Worksheets("Export")




With transactionWorkbook

.Saved = True

.Close

End With
invoiceWorkbook.Sheets("Charge Invoice").Select

End Sub
```

I don't know the range of the transaction worksheet or I'd just use .Range.Copy after the user had selected the file.
I'm not sure how to get this to happen. Many thanks for any help!

Comment: Do you actually have a worksheet called "Sheets" in your transaction workbook? Something like "Sheet1" would be more usual as this the default name that Excel normally uses in English language versions. The error message suggests that one of the worksheet names you are using in this part of the code is your problem.

Comment: It is actually named Sheet. But, you are right, excel didn't like that. When I renamed the sheet and the call here, it worked. Either that or I did something else different that made the macro work right.

Comment: Know this is late, but `transactionWorkbook.Sheets(1).UsedRange` will select all the data from the source workbook's single worksheet that you could then paste.